# hiding all divs except the one you want to see

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a project, but I want to hide all the divs, except the one you want to see. I've looked it up and came across many people who have the same problem, but their solutions didn't work. Here's my basic code:

```
    <!doctype HTML>
<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
  <div>
    <div id="container">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1a4Z3tB.png" title="Tesla Motors" id="tsl_logo"/>
    <button class="btn" id="home_btn">
      <b>Home</b>
    </button>
      <button class="btn" id="roadster_btn">
      <b>Tesla Roadster</b>
    </button>
    <button class="btn" id="s_btn">
      <b>Tesla Model S</b>
    </button>
    <button class="btn" id="x_btn">
      <b>Tesla Model X</b>
    </button>
    <button class="btn" id="3_btn">
      <b>Tesla Model 3</b>
    </button>
     <button class="btn" id="founder_btn">
      <b>Oprichter</b>
    </button>
      <button class="btn" id="about_btn">
        <b>Over Tesla</b>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </header>
  <div id="bg"/>
    <div id="text">
      <div id="home_txt" class="para_text">
    <h2><b>
      Inleiding
      </b>
    </h2>
    <p id="inleiding">
    <b><u>De Opdracht:</u></b><br><br>
// information
    </p>
    <p>
      <b><u>Mijn Keuze:</u></b><br><br><img src="http://i.imgur.com/eWJnnGN.png?1" id="tsl_tblt" align="right"/>
   // information
    </p>
  </div>
      <div id="roadster_txt" class="para_text">
        // information
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home_btn').click(function(){
      $('.para_text').hide(); // Hide all tabs with class para_text
      $('#home_txt').show(); // Show only the tab you want to show
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#roadster_btn').click(function(){
        $('.para_text').hide(); // Hide all tabs with class para_text
        $('#roadster_txt').show(); // Show only the tab you want to show
      });
</script>
```

If I click on Tesla Roadster I want the div with it's information to appear, and all the other divs to disappear.

Sorry if it is a bit confusing, if you need more information or code, please let me know. I really hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: which div you vant to see ?

Comment: your `$('#roadster_btn').click(` code looks perfect. You must be missing something else. Please provide all of your code.

Comment: You have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue becasue, although your code is not that great, it should work

Comment: There should be only one `$(document).ready(function(){})` in your whole page.

Comment: Since the button id can be easily mapped to the div id, you only need a single `click` event, and a single `ready` event.

Answer (score 1):

If you rethink about it like, changing some attributes:

```
<button class="btn" id="roadster_tesla">
  <b>Tesla Roadster</b> <!--- Only change here is the id: "roadster_tesla" --->
</button>
```

and this is the respective div to the above button:

```
<div id="roadster_txt" class="para_text roadster_tesla">
 <!--- button's id is a part of this div ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --->
 <!--- and this structure will work for other buttons too --->
</div>
```

now you can use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
       $('.para_text').hide(); // Hide all tabs with class para_text
       $('.'+this.id).show(); // Show only the tab you want to show
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, changed the ID's etc but still not working

Comment: could you maybe try to implement it and see if it works, because how I did it it didn't work

Comment: @SamB. This works fine. Did you also added the class to the `div`s?

Comment: Yeah, but if i want to to it for the Model S, do I just add "para_text s_tesla ?

Comment: it works, but when I implement it it doesn't doe anything. Here's mine: [link](http://jsbin.com/yolipediti/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @SamB No wonder it doesn't work. You need to add the jQuery library and add the javascript.

Comment: The JS was in the HTML section with the library, because it I put it in the JS section I get errors and warnings

Comment: @SamB In JsBin you should place only HTML in the Html pane, Place the javascript in the Javascript pane. And add external scripts in the "Add library" menu. Works for me. You might try out in jsFiddle as well.

Comment: but in the editor I'm using (thimble from Mozilla) it's still not working but in jsfiddle it is

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    var id = "#" + $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0] + "_txt";
    $("div.para_text").hide();
    $("div" + id).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="home_btn"> <b>Home</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="roadster_btn"> <b>Tesla Roadster</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="s_btn"> <b>Tesla Model S</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="x_btn"> <b>Tesla Model X</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="3_btn"> <b>Tesla Model 3</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="founder_btn"> <b>Founder</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="about_btn"> <b>About Tesla</b>
</button>

<div class="para_text" id="home_txt">Home</div>
<div class="para_text" id="roadster_txt">Tesla Roadster</div>
<div class="para_text" id="s_txt">Tesla Model S</div>
<div class="para_text" id="x_txt">Tesla Model X</div>
<div class="para_text" id="3_txt">Tesla Model 3</div>
<div class="para_text" id="founder_txt">Founder</div>
<div class="para_text" id="about_txt">About Tesla</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var attrid = $(this).attr('id');
  var newid = attrid.split('_');
  console.log('div#' + newid[0] + '_txt')
  //$('#roadster_txt').toggle();
  $('#'+newid[0]+'_txt').toggle();
})
```

```css
.para_text {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="home_btn">
  <b>Home</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="roadster_btn">
  <b>Tesla Roadster</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="s_btn">
  <b>Tesla Model S</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="x_btn">
  <b>Tesla Model X</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="3_btn">
  <b>Tesla Model 3</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="founder_btn">
  <b>Founder</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" id="about_btn">
  <b>About Tesla</b>
</button>


<div id="roadster_txt" class="para_text">
  roadster_txt
</div>
<div id="s_txt" class="para_text">
  s_txt
</div>
<div id="x_txt" class="para_text">
  x_txt
</div>
<div id="3_txt" class="para_text">
  3_txt
</div>
<div id="founder_txt" class="para_text">
  founder_txt
</div>
<div id="about_txt" class="para_text">
  about_txt
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1)You can specify in button which div must be shown. Here i use data-container attribute.
2)I guess you need to show only 1 div when page loaded.

```
    <button class="btn" data-container="#home_txt">
  <b>Home</b>
</button>
  <button class="btn" data-container="#roadster_txt">
  <b>Tesla Roadster</b>
</button>
<button class="btn" data-container="#s_txt">
  <b>Tesla Model S</b>
</button>

  <div id="home_txt" class="para_text">
    home
        <--- information --->
  </div>

  <div id="roadster_txt" class="para_text" style="display:none">
    roadster    
    <--- information --->
  </div>

  <div id="s_txt" class="para_text" style="display:none">
    s    
    <--- information --->
  </div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    var t = $(this);
    var c = t.data("container");
    $('.para_text:not('+c+')').hide(); // Hide all tabs with class para_text but target
    $(c).show(); // Show only the tab you want to show
  });
});
```